# Identify contiguous segments of a non-contiguous numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pycuda

In the example below, we have a contiguous array, and a view of the same array
that is non-contiguous:

```
shape = (5, 100)
A = np.arange(np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)

# Everything is contiguous at this point
assert A.flags.c_contiguous == True

# Since we're taking a view over the
# row minor dimension, we'll have 5
# segments of 50 contiguous elements
A[:,20:70].flags.c_contiguous == False

# Each segment is contiguous
A[0,20:70].flags.c_contiguous == True
A[1,20:70].flags.c_contiguous == True
A[2,20:70].flags.c_contiguous == True
A[3,20:70].flags.c_contiguous == True
A[4,20:70].flags.c_contiguous == True
```

The view references 5 segments of 50 contiguous elements.

If we look at a more general case

```
shape = (30, 20, 70, 50)
B = np.arange(np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)
```

then, the following holds:

```
B[0,:,:,:].flags.c_contiguous == True
B[0,0,:,:].flags.c_contiguous == True
B[0,0,0,:].flags.c_contiguous == True
```

A partial solution, based on _UpdateContiguousFlags in flagobjects.c might be:

```
def is_contiguous(ary):
    is_c_contig = True
    sd = ary.itemsize
    for i in reversed(range(ary.ndim)):
        dim = ary.shape[i]

        # Contiguous by default
        if dim == 0:
            return True

        if dim != 1:
            if ary.strides[i] != sd:
                is_c_contig = False

            sd *= dim

    return is_c_contig
```

But I don't think this handles cases where the array is transposed. e.g.:

```
B.transpose(3,0,1,2)
```

**Question:** Is there a method of identifying the contiguous segments in a general NumPy view/array?

I need this functionality in order to transfer data from a NumPy array to a GPU without copying data into `pinned memory`. Instead, I'd like to pin contiguous segments using `cudaHostRegister` and then do the transfer to the GPU. I'm aware of CUDA's support for pitched memory via `MemCpy3D`, but I'd like to handle more general cases.

**Edit 1:** Added a basic solution to the question, and asked about the transpose case.

**Edit 2:** Clarified removing the need to copy data into pinned memory.

Comment: If `A` is `c_contiguous`, then any simple slice on the last dimension will also be.  `A[2,10:20]` is, `A[3,10:20:2]` is not, or is `A[1;5,3]`.  Once you understand the data layout and slicing you can predict what wil be contiguous.

Comment: @hpaulj if you want to flesh that out into an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: *"I need this functionality in order to transfer data from a NumPy array to a GPU without creating copies"* - what makes you think that's possible? The array data is either in RAM or VRAM - there's no way to avoid creating a copy when transferring from one to the other.

Comment: @ali_m I've made a second edit. Essentially, I'd like to pin contiguous segments of memory for transfer to the GPU, instead of making an extra copy of existing data into a pinned array and *then* doing the transfer.

Comment: Why don't you just try registering the memory with `pycuda.driver.register_host_memory`and catch the exception if the registration fails? Also note that the transpose case you are wondering about doesn't actual change the underlying storage in any way, it just signals to the API to use the alternative storage order to that which the array use during reads, so you can probably forget about it in this context

Comment: Looks like the 1D and 2D cases are handled by [`_memcpy_discontig`](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/dae67bfae98d67a4346821dddde39aecf5f1a95b/pycuda/gpuarray.py#L1088) function recently introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/pull/76).